# Transparency Acting Strangely Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I am trying to get a transparent material in my scene on a white backround (2D). It seems though that even with the camera background color set to white, and a background that is just a big white square, the transparent gameobjects still look like they are on a black background.

[Here is a screenshot of my transparent material:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UbPp.png)

[Here is a screenshot of the game view:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTnPj.png)

Like I said earlier, the white background on the camera game object AND the white background that I made using a 2d square with the color set to white, the transparency still doesn't work. I can not think of anything else to do besides this.

Comment: The rendering mode is set to `Opaque` on the material.  Set to `Transparent`.